# We are no longer going to support SSLv3 but we want to redirect Browsers using SSLv3 to another page

Tags: apache, ssl

We were just notified by Akamai that they are no longer going to accept the SSLv3 CipherSpec.

We will soon be disabling SSLv3 on our web servers, and in tests we get "Unknown Protocol" Errors.  We don't want to just leave our customers hanging with that weere, and would like to Redirect them to an informational page instead.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If Akamai is your hosting provider, which isn't clear from your question, you don't have any way of doing this. They will terminate the incoming SSL connection and reject SSLv3 before you even get to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question. Since your server will not respond to a SSLv3 request and the browser will only report a "Secure Connection Failed" error message, it gives the user no clue on what went wrong. So, you want to inform the users how they can fix the issue.

I am not sure if that would work for Akamai but my suggestion would be to do a mod_rewrite redirection based on a condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_PROTOCOL} ^SSLv3$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://zmap.io/sslv3/ [L,R=302]
```

This redirects it to https://zmap.io/sslv3/ but you can change the URL to your own help page as needed.